# How to correct POS tagging errors?

Tags: python, nltk

I currently have a text file containing a few hundred words which I am trying to pos tag in python. The file contains already tokenized words. When applying the pos tagger to these words, most are incorrectly tagged with the most frequent tags being POS or CD. I know that pos taggers are not 100% accurate but in this case, there are so many incorrect POS and CD tags being applied that I think I may need to format the input file or change something with the tagger to get the correct tags.

As mentioned previously there are a few hundred words in the txt file so I have provided a small example of the words and format which they are in. The file is called `token.txt`:

```
['research', 'interests', 'member', 'language', 'computation']
```

The python code is:

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import *

f = open('token.txt')
data=f.read().split()
fire = nltk.pos_tag(data)
print(fire)
```

The current result for this small sample is:

```
[("['research',", 'JJ'), ("'interests',", 'POS'), ("'member',", 'POS'), ("'language',", 'CD'), ("'computation']", 'NNS')]
```

I know interests should be tagged NNS and member should be tagged NN as well as language. The incorrect tagging is happening throughout the document

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: When I run nltk.pos_tag on the sample data you gave, I get: `[('research', 'NN'),
 ('interests', 'NNS'),
 ('member', 'NN'),
 ('language', 'NN'),
 ('computation', 'NN')]` ... so I'm not sure what's going on with yours. But one thing I'll point out is that POS taggers are generally designed to work with complete sentences, and lists of words like this can't be reliably tagged by them. Most of the words in that list can be different parts of speech depending on context (for instance "interests" can be a noun or a verb, as can "research")

Comment: I see, thanks for explaining this. I hadn't taken context into account. Also did you run my program exactly how it was in the question to get that result or did you make any changes?

Comment: @J.Taylor Also, it seems that when the `token.txt` file has double quotes around the tokens, I get a completely different result to when there are single quotes around them

Comment: I couldn't run your program exactly like it was in the question, because I don't have access to 'token.txt'. I just created the example list you gave and ran `nltk.pos_tag(the_list)`. I have no idea why you would be getting different results based on single vs. double quotes though

Comment: @J.Taylor `token.txt` is literally just a small sample text file which I created containing `['research', 'interests', 'member', 'language', 'computation']` exactly how I've copied it in here, nothing else